# How to print dependencies list using single variable?

Tags: makefile

I have created a make file with list of variables. I have added all the files list and assigned to a variable in that make file.

```
ROLS= \
$(wildcard *.c)
```

The files list is more than 10000. when I try to print this variable using below rule , it is not printing all the files list.

```
all:
    @echo $(ROLS)
```

How to print entire list of "c" files in a single variable.
I am using windows 7 64bit system to run this makefile.

Comment: When you say >10000, do you mean that there are that many *files,* or that many *elements in the list?* You can get the number of elements in the list with `$(words ROLS)`

Comment: When you say it's not printing all the files, what does it actually do?  Does it print an error?  What is the error?  Does it print no files?  Does it print some but not all?  How are you sure (note that the results of wildcard may not be sorted so just because the last names are not alphabetically last doesn't mean they're not all there).

Comment: @MadScientist , it is not throwing an error. It is printing some of the files , but not all of them. I have noticed as at  the end of the printing , it is showing half of the next file path. Then i noticed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a limit on the complete size of a command line that it will accept.  There's nothing make can do about that, it's a hard limit by the operating system.

If all you want to do is actually print the content, then you can use make's internal `info` function instead so it doesn't try to invoke a Windows command:

```
all:
        $(info $(ROLS))
```

Of course that won't help if you're trying to do something else with those files that requires a command to be invoked.

Comment: i want to provide this entire list to a target as dependency to check is there any update on these files. can we use **info** for this?

Comment: Uh, no.  Info (as the docs say) simply prints its arguments.  But since make's entire purpose is to check for updates on files, you don't need to put this list of files into a single recipe.  Make them prerequisites and write a rule to "check is there any update" for a single file.  Then make will apply that rule for each file one at a time.

Comment: If what you want to do has nothing to do with the question you asked, then why ask it?  XY problems http://xyproblem.info/ or not productive uses of anyone's time.  Why not try to write a makefile that does what you _actually_ want to do and if you can't get it to work, then post a question about _that_?

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional information in comments:

```
ROLS= $(wildcard *.c)

target: $(ROLS)
   build-target
```

Or if ROLS used more than once, some efficiency can be achieved with phony target

```
ROLS= $(wildcard *.c)

.PHONY: all-rols
all-rols: $(ROLS)

target1: all-rols
     build-target1

target2: all-rols
     build-target2

target3: all-rols
     build-target3
```